# Compositing Multiple Templates in jTemplates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtemplate

Using jTemplates, it is possible to composite templates like so...

```
<textarea id="templateList" class="template"><!--

  {#template RESULTS}
    This a template for generating a list of results
    {#include PAGINATION root=$T}
  {#/template RESULTS}

  {#template PAGINATION}
    This is a template for generating pagination through the results
  {#/template PAGINATION}

--></textarea>
```

However there are times when it would be handy to be be able to composite completely different templates.  For example, I have a lot of different types of lists, each of which has a distinct template.  Using the method above, I am forced to keep repeating the same chunk of code for pagination over and over in each of my templates for different lists.

I would much rather do something like the following...

```
<textarea id="templateList" class="template"><!--
  This is a template listing results
  {#some kind of call to templatePagination}
--></textarea>

<textarea id="templatePagination" class="template"><!--
  This is a template for generating pagination
--></textarea>
```

Does anyone know if such a thing is possible and, if so, how to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can append all your needed templates together when you `setTemplate` if you have no template refrence.

```
$(container)
   .setTemplate($('templateList').html() + $('templatePagination').html())
```

or you can `createTemplate` and pass the reference as a `include`

```
var t = $.createTemplate($('templatePagination').html());
$(container).setTemplate($('templateList').html(), t._templates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
var templates = $.createTemplate($('templateList').html())._templates;
```

Then you can use templates and do:

```
$('#SOMEDIV').setTemplate(templates['PAGINATION'],templates);
&('#SOMEDIV').processTemplate(data);
```

I'm a js/jquery newbie so sorry if its not perfect. I'm loading it from a url using $.createTemplateURL instead of a text areas we